# What should i add in path for using mvn commands if i have only maven wrapper from Inteleji?

Tags: java, maven, path

I have faced such a problem: i have a home project with maven, it was pulled automatically through Inteligi IDE and now i need to change my liquibase checkSum using mvn commands, but it doesn't work cause my machine can't recognize this command.

I tried to add in path the following directories:
C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\tutorial\tutorial.mvn\wrapper
C:\Users\myUser\m2\repository

i tried to use commands **mvn, mvnw** and it didn't work out

Basically i need to set up maven on my computer and add it to Path variable but i use maven wrapper there should be some way not to setup regular maven. If you have some ideas i'll be grateful

Answer (score 0):

I have found the correct path, it's C:\Users\MyUser.m2\wrapper\dists\apache-maven-3.8.4-bin being MyUser your user in the system for Windows.

also you can use the maven executor button in Intellij [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDo6C.png)

Hope it might be useful for someone

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).